# Django how hide empty category

Tags: html, django

I have a hoodie category and two gender divisions male and female. How can I hide a category hoodie for a gender that does not have this product?

```
    {% get_genders as genders %}
                    {% for gender in genders %}
                <li>
                    <!-- First Tier Drop Down -->
                    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Категории <span class="fa fa-angle-down"
                                                                       aria-hidden="true"></span> </label>

                    <a href="/">{{ gender }} <span class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2">

                    <ul>
                        {% get_category as categories %}
                        {% for category in categories %}
                        <li><a href="{%  url 'category' gender_slug=gender.slug category_slug=category.slug %}">{{category.name}}</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
```

I'm try make many to many field gender for category, but I don't know how to write in html

models.py

```
class Gender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Гендер'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Гендеры'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('gender', kwargs={'gender_slug': self.slug})

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.ManyToManyField(Gender)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
      
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130699/many-to-many-items-in-a-template-check-if-any-are-not-empty-or-none

Comment: I tried to do this, but I still get all the categories.

Comment: Maybe I don't remember something but `{% get_category as categories %}` syntax looks like a typo for me. What does it seems to mean?

Comment: Also, adding `views.py` would be nice.

Comment: {% get_category as categories %} derived from simple tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got it
It took to add new tag

```py
@register.simple_tag()
def get_all(gender, category):
    stuff = Stuff.objects.filter(gender=gender, category=category).first()
    if stuff is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```