# How to hide a category without articles?

Tags: python, django, hide, categories

I have articles combined by categories. Here are data models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Наименование')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, verbose_name='URL')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Добавлено')

    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'категорию'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:article_list_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Article(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('draft', 'Черновик'),
        ('published', 'Опубликовано'),
    )
    TYPE_ARTICLE_CHOICES = (
        ('Руководство', 'Руководство'),
        ('Инструкция', 'Инструкция'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish', verbose_name='URL')
    type_article = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=TYPE_ARTICLE_CHOICES, default='Инструкция',
                                    verbose_name='Тип статьи')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,
                                 related_name='article',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts', verbose_name='Автор')
    body = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name='Статья')
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Опубликовано')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Добавлено')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Обновлено')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft', verbose_name='Статус')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Приватная статья')

    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)
        verbose_name = 'статью'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Статьи'
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=['title'])]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is the output template:

```
<div class="container my-container-style">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4 class="mb-4 category">Категории</h4>
            <div id="sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li {% if not category %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
                        <a href="{% url 'main:articles_list' %}">Все</a>
                    </li>
                    {% for c in categories %}
                    <li {% if category.slug == c.slug %} class="selected" {% endif %}>
                        <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.name }}</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            {% if tag %}
            <h2 class="tag_title">Статьи с тегами: "{{ tag.name }}"</h2>
            {% endif %}
            {% for articles in Article %}
            <div class="article col-md-12">
                <a href="{{ articles.get_absolute_url }}"><h2 class="article_title">{{ articles.title }}</h2></a>
                <div class="article_info">
                    <span>Автор: {{ articles.author.first_name }} &#171{{ articles.author }}&#187 {{ articles.author.last_name }}</span>
                    <span>Обновлено: {{ articles.updated|date:'d-m-Y' }}</span>
                    <span>Тип статьи: {{ articles.type_article }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="article_body">
                    <p>{{ articles.body|safe|truncatewords:30 }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="read_more">
                    <p class="mb-4"><a class="btn btn-secondary button_read back" href="{{ articles.get_absolute_url }}" role="button">Читать далее &#187;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% include "pagination.html" with page=Article %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've found similar question ([Django how hide empty category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907496/django-how-hide-empty-category)) but I can't hide a category with my own filter. How to properly hide a category with zero articles in it?

Comment: Why don't you just fetch the articles that do have a category from the start?

Comment: I have private articles, they're in one category. I wanted to hide them from unregistered users, these categories have 0 articles or have "private" ones that only admin has rights to see.

Comment: If you want to display something only for "admin" you can check in the template if the user is an admin or not. If admin show, else show nothing. For example using `request.user.is_admin` or `request.user.is_authenticated` or both ? `{% if request.user.is_admin and request.user.is_authenticated %} show something {% else %} show something else {% endif %}`

Comment: Internal checks don't fit in this case well cause admin will see all the categories, but common user will see nothing. I need to hide a category in which every article is private.

Comment: Internal checks? I don't think I understand, but there are endless possibilities to achieve what you want. You have some articles that are only for spesific users based on the category. You could do that in the loop, if admin show this if not dont show it. Or if a category has no articles, don't show it. If there is something else here you need to show all the code, for example the view.

Comment: In part of the code my views: def articles_list(request, category_slug=None, tag_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    object_list = Article.published.filter(private=False)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        object_list = Article.published.all()
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(category=category)